# checktable with repari_allow_data_loss taking so much time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I am not sure whats going on.
But,
When i run

```
alter database myDatabase set emergency  
ALTER DATABASE myDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE  
dbcc checktable ('myTable', repair_allow_data_loss)  
alter database myDatabase set multi_user
```

Its taking so much time.
(running for last 30 minutes and still running)
Can anyone tell me, is something going wrong or this is the normal behaviour of checktable.

I am using sql server 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you running with repair_allow_data_loss anyway? You normally shouldn't.

Comment: yes, you are right. i shouldn't use it,,, but some pages of my database tables are corrupted (actually 6 pages). and unfortunately, i have no backup.
thats why, i want to repair those tables (i can bear data loss from those pages)

Comment: @urs is there any other way to get rid of those corrupted data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal behavior. Please check SQL server log. There should be % completed logged.

Please run it.

```
SELECT r.session_id,r.command,CONVERT(NUMERIC(6,2),r.percent_complete)
AS [Percent Complete],CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(ms,r.estimated_completion_time,GetDate()),20) AS [ETA Completion Time],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.total_elapsed_time/1000.0/60.0) AS [Elapsed Min],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.estimated_completion_time/1000.0/60.0) AS [ETA Min],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.estimated_completion_time/1000.0/60.0/60.0) AS [ETA Hours],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000),(SELECT SUBSTRING(text,r.statement_start_offset/2,
CASE WHEN r.statement_end_offset = -1 THEN 1000 ELSE (r.statement_end_offset-r.statement_start_offset)/2 END)
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)))
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r WHERE command = ('DBCC TABLE CHECK')
```

You can check what it is doing at this moment. Please put session_id of DBCC statement.

```
SELECT session_id,command,(SELECT text
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle))
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
WHERE session_id =
```

Comment: sql server log only shows that the emergency is ON. i can't see any sign of % completed :( ,,, :(...
Btw,, thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Please run this query for time estimate.

Comment: didn't get anything from this query :( ...  I just updated my question. may be you come up with any suggestion....